# How to retrieve the id of an object inside of other object in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in my database:

```
user
   - l5tCeZmcZtXLITJugdtfHsK647s1
      email: "myemail@sample.com"
      name: "Bob"
   - userType
       guestType: 1
   - MyObject
       Kke0cr5NUGEgg3rq_Mf: true // I can get the value true but I need to the key Kke0cr5NUGEgg3rq_Mf
```

How can I get only the id of the object MyObject and put it in a variable.

This is that I've tried to do:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseUtil.USER).child(user.getUid());

        mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String weedingCode = dataSnapshot.child("MyObject").getKey();


            }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach

Comment: Firebase doesn't have an id parameter, only key:value pairs aka parent:child. Are you looking for MyObject or the child Kke0cr...? Either way this guide will help [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)